# Javascript cycling text

Tags: javascript

I used it and it worked perfect... and now I don't understand why it stopped working... I'm not a programmer so if I deleted something by mistake it's hars for me to find it... I did look everything... everything seems fine to me... please can you tell me why I now have UNDEFINED error ?

I have this in my heading :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/textCycle.js"></script>
```

and this in my body tag :

```
<body onload="changeText()">
```

and this is where the script should be :

```
<table border = 0><tr><td style="width:300px;" height="100px"> <!-- Change the height in order to determine width of quotes -->
    <div id="change"></div></td></tr></table>
```

and this is my JS :

```
var quotes=new Array(5);
var i = 0;
var authors=new Array(5);

//Load Quotes into array
quotes[0]="\"Temoignage #1\"";authors[0]="Client #1";

quotes[1]="\"Temoignage #2\"";authors[1]="Client #2";

quotes[2]="\"Temoignage #3\"";authors[2]="Client #3";

quotes[3]="\"Temoignage #4\"";authors[3]="Client #4";

quotes[4]="\"Temoignage #5\"";authors[4]="Client #5";


//Call the changeText() function every 5000 miliseconds
setInterval(changeText, 3000);

//Function that determine what quote and author to put in html.
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=(quotes[i] + '<p style="text-align: right"><i>' + authors[i] + '</i></p>');
    if(i == 4)
        i = 0;
    else
        i++;
}
```

I changed a few things in the JS and it was working... And suddently it stopped working after doing something (this is the something I can't remember!) and I'd like to know what is wrong with my code?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you give the exact `undefined` error? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Works fine for me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkxx0may/)

Comment: Did you try `Ctl + Z`? :)

Comment: Can you share some fiddle ?

Comment: Instead of writing what is in the JS, it says Undefined.

Maybe I can give you the link to my webpage : www.antoinewistaff.com

I know it stopped working after changing something somewhere (I think not related) and I told myself I'LL FIX IT LATER... and I forgot what change caused this error message to show... I feel stupid for that... I'm pretty sure my code is good everywhere but a conflict somewhere make it show Undefined on the webpage where it should be the Customer comment....

Comment: looks just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3L3Lonbn/1/

Comment: @SimplePsycho I wish I could but it too far...

Comment: It works there, but can you find any error in the webpage that would make it write UNDEFINED instead of js text... ?

Comment: Sorry for being stupid there.... I don't know why but my StatCounter code was creating a conflict.... when I delete it, my JS works.... Thank you all, and sorry for this!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is another global `i` variable on your page, which is set to some arbitrarily high number bigger than the size of your `quotes` array, so it's undefined.

Rename `i` to something more descriptive like `currentClientIndex` and you should be good.

Comment: OK this causes the UNDEFINED
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=9688368; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="e1141dcb"; 
var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
"https://secure." : "http://www.");document.write("<sc"+"ript
type='text/javascript' src='" +
scJsHost+"statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
</script><noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="free web stats"
href="http://statcounter.com/free-web-stats/"target="_blank"><img class="statcounter"src="http://c.statcounter.com/9688368/0/e1141dcb/1/"lt="free web stats"></a></div></noscript>

Comment: Interesting...but in any event, you should still use more descriptive names for global variables just in case there is a conflict.

Comment: I changed the i for currentClientIndex in my JS and no more conflict! Thank you!